# RegEx for maximum length in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, maxlength

How can I limit the length of a string matching a RegEx

I assumed that `var sixCharsRegEx = /^.{6,7}/` would only match strings of lengths 6 or 7

but no: http://jsfiddle.net/FEXbB/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You are missing closing dollar at the end. Correct one is: `/^.{6,7}$/`

Comment: $ in this case means, that the 6th or 7th char will the last one.

Answer (score 9):

Match the start and the end.

```
var sixCharsRegEx = /^.{6,7}$/;
```

**[Your improved example](http://jsfiddle.net/FEXbB/1/)**

Answer (score 6):

you must use end of string symbol `$`

like this `^.{6,7}$`

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the end anchor:

```
var sixCharsRegEx = /^.{6,7}$/
```