# Regex for String in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

How shall we write a regular expression to validate a string that should have a length of a minimum of 1 character and a maximum of 50 characters, have both upper case and lower case, alphanumeric, include space, and have mostly used special characters like **@,._-&$#**? The first character should be either alphabet or number then the rest can be as mentioned above.

*If it is only one character then it should be an alphanumeric one

I have tried a regex with my limited knowledge which looks like

```
^[a-zA-z]*[a-zA-Z\d\-_@&$%#\s]{1,50}$
```

But I am not able to match the string if there is only one character given, can anyone guide me to fix this

Comment: Can include one space or more?

Comment: Can Include 1 or more spaces but the begining of the text should be an alphabet @alextrastero

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will check that as well @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511154 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605150.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have tried to create a regex with my limited knowledge and your reference and i have edited the question with that. can you help me fix this

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z][\w@,.&$%#\s-]{0,49}$`. Or `^(?=[a-zA-Z])[\w@,.&$%#\s-]{1,50}$`

Comment: its working..Thanks a lot @WiktorStribiżew .. I had one more question once the language is changed for this from english and the input is coming in some other language, like lets say swedish , then this regex will fail right. If yes, do we any way to fix that?

Comment: Aha, so you want to use a Unicode-aware `\w`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62772689/3832970), and you will need to use `/^(?=\p{Alphabetic})[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}@,.&$%#\s-]{1,50}$/u`

Comment: So, what do you need?

Comment: Need to know a method which will validate and pass the string even in case of internationalization. the above reference was confusing me pretty much, what do you suggest me to do @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Either learn regex or pass this task to a colleague.

Comment: Not willing to give up.. will learn about it more and will make it work..Thanks for your time and help..Really appreciated @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: got a regex for it

    `^(?=[\p{​​​​​L}​​​​​0-9])[\w@,.&$%#\s-]{​​​​​1,50}​​​​​$` was doing the job..even `\w` instead of `\p{L}` can be used. but in my case the beginning letter doesnt need to be a unicode digit so used `[\p{L}]`

Thanks for giving me the reference and teaching me @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
/^(?=[\p{L}0-9])[\p{L}\p{N}_@,.&$%#\s-]{1,50}$/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH6vi6/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[\p{L}0-9])` - the first char must be a Unicode letter (`\p{L}`) or an ASCII digit
- `[\p{L}\p{N}_@,.&$%#\s-]{1,50}` - one to fifty

  - `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
  - `\p{N}` - any Unicode digit
  - `_@,.&$%#-` - any of these chars
  - `\s` - any whitespace
- `$` - end of string.